# how to find last visible column number in vba?

Tags: excel, vba

How to find  the last visible column (not hidden) in sheet using vba?

I have used the code below:

```
Dim LastColumn As Integer
If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Cells) > 0 Then
            'Search for any entry, by searching backwards by Columns.

LastColumn = Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=[A1], SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column

MsgBox LastColumn
End If
```

But it gives me last column number. I want last visible column number.
Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below. You can use xlCellTypeVisible to specify hidden vs non hidden cells.

```
Sub counthidden()
MsgBox ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Columns.Count
End Sub
```

Comment: That doesn't return the last visible column. It counts the visible columns

Comment: Read the question a little too fast i guess :) ...upvoted your solution.

Comment: Thank you, brettdj.  Glad to be of help, Abhijeet.

Answer (score 3):

You can use SpecialCells to help:

```
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range

On Error Resume Next
Set rng1 = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlVisible)
On Error GoTo 0

If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
    Set rng2 = rng1.Find(What:="*", After:=rng1.Cells(1), SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
    MsgBox rng2.Column
End If
```

Comment: Thanks a lo friend. It helps a lot in my project. Many thanks.

Comment: @Abhijeet no probs. I see you awarded the answer to me, then you changed it to Eric. Not sure you meant to do this?

Comment: Actually, Both the codes are best and very helpful.But as code by Eric is one liner and fast (less clock cycle of CPU per code line execution), i changed it to Eric. Sorry for inconvenience caused .

Comment: @Abhijeet No problem:) Although as above I don't think it does exactly what you want.

Comment: Thanks for understanding :)

Answer (score 1):

Surprisingly simple as it turns out. I was looking for a similar problem.

```
Sub lastVisibleColumn()
' This should select the last fully visible column on the active window

' This part selects the current top left visible cell regardless of zoom
    ActiveWindow.VisibleRange.Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0).Select
    startColumn = ActiveCell.Column

' Large scroll right 1 page
    ActiveWindow.LargeScroll ToRight:=1
    ActiveWindow.VisibleRange.Select

' Select the top left cell again, -1 column to get to
'the previous scrollable page
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Select
    ActiveWindow.LargeScroll ToLeft:=1
    lastColumn = ActiveCell.Column
End Sub
```